# Creating buttons inside loop command failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Using Tkinter in python, trying to make numbered buttons, which use self.do(x) to add the number x to a string variable. The problem with this particular piece of code being in a loop (to save space), is that it will add the LAST number to the string (ie, 9 in this example). This is because it calls the function after this, and uses the latest value of num[i]. Is there any way to correct this?

```
self.numButton = []
num = []
for i in range(9):
    num.append(i + 1)
    self.numButton.append(Button(root,text=num[i],command=lambda: self.do(num[i])))
```

Comment: That long line is pretty hard to read. Can you break it out into more than one line or create a function to remove the inessential parts from the question?

Comment: There you go, the length is pretty essential, but I took out the parts that are not generally required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value in your `lambda` function:

```
self.numButton.append(
    Button(root,text=num[i],command=lambda i=i: self.do(num[i])))
```

The default value is evaluated and bound to the function at the time the `lambda` function is *defined* (as opposed to when it is run). So, later, when the button is pressed and the callback is called *without any arguments*, the default value is used.

Since a different default value for `i` is bound to each `lambda` function, the appropriate value for `i` is used for each callback.

---

If the callback requires additional arguments, such as on `event`, just place the parameter with default value at the end. For example,

```
root.bind('Key-{n}'.format(n=num[i]), lambda e, i=i: self.do(num[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I knew I was missing something. As an extension to the question, how would I bind self.do(x) to a key, when I simultaneously need lambda  e: and lambda i=i: ?    'root.bind(str(num[i]),lambda e: self.do(num[i]))'

Comment: `root.bind('Key-{n}'.format(n=num[i]), lambda e, i=i: self.do(num[i]))`